# Relation between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes:

df:

```
   points
0  a,b,c
1  a,e
2  d,f,c
```

and df1:

```
point relation
a     [b,f,e]
b     []
c     [e]
```

and i want to keep only the points on the first dataframe that have a relation between them (using the second dataframe).

What i've tried :

I tried converting the second dataframe to a dictionary and search for the points in the first dataframe but i had no luck because it was searching the whole dataframe.

I tried a sort of combination of the 2 dataframes into one with only the common elements but again i had no luck.
Any suggestions out there? Thank you in advance

**Edit**

Desire output

```
    points
 0  a,b
 1  a,e
 2  []
```

code:

```
my_dict = df1.set_index('point')['relation'].to_dict() #create dict
my_dict = dict((k, v) for k, v in my_dict.items() if v) #delete empty []
for key, values in my_dict.items():
    if df['point'].str.contains(key,values).any():
```

but then i saw with print that the code in not working

Comment: please clarify the desired output with an example. also, please show actual code snippet of what you have tried.

Comment: I updated the post with the requested information